# itextpdf-5.5.6.jar: Error: The file name must end with .xml

Tags: java, android, jar

[image]Hi all,

I have been trying to import a jar into my android studio and for now say im using the jar itextpdf 5.5.6.jar and trying to import that jar and when i clean my project I'm getting this error anyone knows how to fix this ??

any help would be off great use.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a `res/libs/` directory, and you put the JAR in there. That is not where JARs go.

Usually, there is already a `libs/` directory in `app/` set up for you. Put the JAR there, and ensure that your `dependencies` closure in `app/build.gradle` contains the `implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` line.